# How to make it so I don't have to press "^" button twice to get the "^" symbol

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I have a Scandinavian layout keyboard and when I press the button which is supposed to make the "^" symbol so I could type for ex. 2^2, I need to press it twice because otherwise it makes just 2², which would be fine for normal text, but many math programs don't understand that, but rather implement their own way to show powers. Is there a way to make it so I'd only have to press the button once to type "^". An extra bonus would be if I could make it only happen in specific apps (GeoGebra, TI-Nspire CX CAS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fully defined by your keyboard layout. For the US keyboard, there are variants that also support dead keys. If one does not want it temporarily, it is simply a matter of switching to the variant without dead keys.

You can see whether such alternative layouts are also available for Scandinavian. In `Settings`, go to `Region & Language`. Clicking on the `+` button allows you to add keyboard layouts. Once multiple keyboard layouts are installed, you can switch between them with the hotkey <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.

Comment: My language is Spanish.

I install by default the English-USA layour and I enable the composition key to insert the special characters of my language.

I already got used.
But before I used your solution, until I decided to buy an American English keyboard on the desktop PC.

Comment: This worked best for me, just needed to know the term was dead keys. This isn't perfect because I need them sometimes, but I can switch layouts easily enough, so that's fine.

Comment: "French alt. no dead Keys" works for french

Answer (score 0):

You can open `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/latin` for editing and change `key <AD12>` for **type2**, i.e. replace `dead_circumflex` with `circumflex`.